# How to go to next image once the image is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nine images arranged in grid 3x3. When i click on each image it will then pop out. I also have <> signs which helps to go to the previous and next image. How can I make the images to go to the next when the image is clicked? When i reach the last image,it should go back to the first one?

This is what I have currently:

```
<body>
        <div id="image">
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/01.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(1);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/02.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(2);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/03.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(3);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/04.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(4);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/05.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(5);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/06.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(6);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/07.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(7);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/08.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(8);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
            <div><img src="Thumbnail/09.jpg" onClick="javascript:show(9);" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="prepage"> 
            <table width="600px" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" valign="middle">
                        <div id="outerDiv">
                            <div id="closeIcon" onClick="hide();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                            <div id="leftIcon" onClick="prevPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                            <div id="rightIcon" onClick="nextPic();" onMouseOver="showIcon();"></div>
                            <img id="largeImg" name="largeImg" src="Original/01.jpg" border="0" onMouseOver="showIcon();" onMouseOut="hideIcon();">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Not enough information is included to provide an answer.  A basic structure of your grid would help us help you with an answer.  There are so many different wants this can be accomplished, but more information is needed.

Comment: You'll need to post your code so we know what you're talking about and can see what you've tried.

Comment: use the same handler as for **>** button, for handle "click" on image.

Comment: @eicto : I see. I'm having problem on how to adjust my css and html to make it happen. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have your images in a div with id 'grid'.

```
<div id='grid'><img......</div>
```

Then let's say you've put your images tags so that they are in order left to right, top to bottom.

```
//lets get all the images
var imgs=document.getElementById('grid').getElementsByTagName('img');

//store a variable to double check one is selected
var areAnySelected=false;

//loop through the images
for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){

   //add code here to find the image selected. I'll use by class Name 'selected'
   if(imgs[i].className=='selected'){
       areAnySelected=true;
        //unset selected
       imgs[i].className='unselected';

        // set selected as next one if not at end
       if(i<imgs.length-1){
           img[i+1].className='selected';
       }

       // set first one as selected if at end
       else{
            imgs[0].className='selected';
        }
}

if(anyAreSelected===false){
     //select first one if nothing is selected
     imgs[0].className='selected'    
}
```